# LLRP for Zebra FX7500 with llrpjs doesn't read tags

Tags: node.js, iot, rfid, llrp, zebra-scanners

Using the [llrpjs library](https://github.com/llrpjs/llrpjs) for Node.js, we are attempting to read tags from the Zebra FX7500 (Motorola?).  [This discussion](https://supportcommunity.zebra.com/s/question/0D56S000097xCT3SAM/how-to-apply-autonomous-mode-operation-on-fix-rfid-reader-i-had-found-in-section-llrp-custom-extensions-operation-the-operations-but-to-use-them-in-java-link-wwwzebracomcontentdamzebranewiaenusmanualsrfidinterfacecontrolguideenpdf?language=en_US) points to the RFID Reader Software Interface Control Guide pages 142-144, but does not indicate potential values to set up the device.

From what we can gather, we should issue a `SET_READER_CONFIG` with a custom parameter (`MotoDefaultSpec = VendorIdentifier: 161, ParameterSubtype: 102, UseDefaultSpecForAutoMode: true`).  Do we need to include the `ROSpec` and/or `AccessSpec` values as well (are they required)?  After sending the `SET_READER_CONFIG` message, do we still need to send the regular LLRP messages (`ADD_ROSPEC`, `ENABLE_ROSPEC`, `START_ROSPEC`)?  Without the `MotoDefaultSpec`, even after sending the regular LLRP messages, sending a `GET_REPORT` does not retrieve tags nor does a custom message with `MOTO_GET_TAG_EVENT_REPORT`.  They both trigger a `RO_ACCESS_REPORT` event message, but the `tagReportData` is null.

The [README file for llrpjs](https://github.com/llrpjs/llrpjs/blob/master/README.md) lists "Vendor definitions support" as a TODO item.  While that is somewhat vague, is it possible that the library just hasn't implemented custom LLRP extension (messages/parameters) support, which is why none of our attempts are working?  The `MotoDefaultSpec` parameter and `MOTO_GET_TAG_EVENT_REPORT` are custom to the vendor/chipset.  The `MOTO_GET_TAG_EVENT_REPORT` custom message seems to trigger a `RO_ACCESS_REPORT` similar to the base LLRP `GET_REPORT` message, so we assume that part is working.

It is worth noting that [Zebra's 123RFID Desktop setup and optimization tool](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/utilities/123rfid.html) connects and reads tags as expected, so the device and antenna are working (reading tags).

Could these issues be related to the ROSPEC file we are using (see below)?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://llrpjs.github.io/schema/core/encoding/json/1.0/llrp-1x0.schema.json",
  "id": 1,
  "type": "ADD_ROSPEC",
  "data": {
    "ROSpec": {
      "ROSpecID": 123,
      "Priority": 1,
      "CurrentState": "Disabled",
      "ROBoundarySpec": {
        "ROSpecStartTrigger": {
          "ROSpecStartTriggerType": "Immediate"
        },
        "ROSpecStopTrigger": {
          "ROSpecStopTriggerType": "Null",
          "DurationTriggerValue": 0
        }
      },
      "AISpec": {
        "AntennaIDs": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "AISpecStopTrigger": {
          "AISpecStopTriggerType": "Null",
          "DurationTrigger": 0
        },
        "InventoryParameterSpec": {
          "InventoryParameterSpecID": 1234,
          "ProtocolID": "EPCGlobalClass1Gen2"
        }
      },
      "ROReportSpec": {
        "ROReportTrigger": "Upon_N_Tags_Or_End_Of_ROSpec",
        "N": 1,
        "TagReportContentSelector": {
          "EnableROSpecID": true,
          "EnableAntennaID": true,
          "EnableFirstSeenTimestamp": true,
          "EnableLastSeenTimestamp": true,
          "EnableSpecIndex": false,
          "EnableInventoryParameterSpecID": false,
          "EnableChannelIndex": false,
          "EnablePeakRSSI": false,
          "EnableTagSeenCount": true,
          "EnableAccessSpecID": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone having a similar issue, we found that attempting to configure more antennas than the Zebra device has connected caused the entire spec to fail.  In our case, we had two antennas connected, so including antennas 3 and 4 in the spec was causing the problem.

See below for the working ROSPEC.  The extra antennas in the `data.AISpec.AntennaIDs` property were removed and allowed our application to connect and read tags.

We are still having some issues with llrpjs when trying to `STOP_ROSPEC` because it sends an `RO_ACCESS_REPORT` response without a `resName` value.  See [the issue on GitHub](https://github.com/llrpjs/llrpjs/issues/2) for more information.

That said, our application works without sending the `STOP_ROSPEC` command.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://llrpjs.github.io/schema/core/encoding/json/1.0/llrp-1x0.schema.json",
  "id": 1,
  "type": "ADD_ROSPEC",
  "data": {
    "ROSpec": {
      "ROSpecID": 123,
      "Priority": 1,
      "CurrentState": "Disabled",
      "ROBoundarySpec": {
        "ROSpecStartTrigger": {
          "ROSpecStartTriggerType": "Null"
        },
        "ROSpecStopTrigger": {
          "ROSpecStopTriggerType": "Null",
          "DurationTriggerValue": 0
        }
      },
      "AISpec": {
        "AntennaIDs": [1, 2],
        "AISpecStopTrigger": {
          "AISpecStopTriggerType": "Null",
          "DurationTrigger": 0
        },
        "InventoryParameterSpec": {
          "InventoryParameterSpecID": 1234,
          "ProtocolID": "EPCGlobalClass1Gen2",
          "AntennaConfiguration": {
            "AntennaID": 1,
            "RFReceiver": {
              "ReceiverSensitivity": 0
            },
            "RFTransmitter": {
              "HopTableID": 1,
              "ChannelIndex": 1,
              "TransmitPower": 170
            },
            "C1G2InventoryCommand": {
              "TagInventoryStateAware": false,
              "C1G2RFControl": {
                "ModeIndex": 23,
                "Tari": 0
              },
              "C1G2SingulationControl": {
                "Session": 1,
                "TagPopulation": 32,
                "TagTransitTime": 0,
                "C1G2TagInventoryStateAwareSingulationAction": {
                  "I": "State_A",
                  "S": "SL"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "ROReportSpec": {
        "ROReportTrigger": "Upon_N_Tags_Or_End_Of_AISpec",
        "N": 1,
        "TagReportContentSelector": {
          "EnableROSpecID": true,
          "EnableAntennaID": true,
          "EnableFirstSeenTimestamp": true,
          "EnableLastSeenTimestamp": true,
          "EnableTagSeenCount": true,
          "EnableSpecIndex": false,
          "EnableInventoryParameterSpecID": false,
          "EnableChannelIndex": false,
          "EnablePeakRSSI": false,
          "EnableAccessSpecID": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```